# How to display selected contact using pickContact() - ionic-v3

Tags: ionic3, ionic-native

i want display selected contact detail in input, in alert showing contact details. so i want display that contact detail in my form. any idea how to do…please help!

home.ts

```
import { Contact, ContactField, ContactName, Contacts } from '@ionic-native/contacts';
: 
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private contacts: Contacts) {
    this.contacts.pickContact().then((contact)=>{
        alert("contacts:-->"+ JSON.stringify(contact));
    });
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <form (ngSubmit)="saveItem()" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.displayName" name="displayName"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Phone</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="tel" [(ngModel)]="contact.phoneNumbers" name="phoneNumbers"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Birth</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="contact.birthday" name="birthday"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Simply assign model to selected contact response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
contact = {
   displayName:null, 
   phoneNumbers:null, 
   birthday:null
};

selectContact(){
   this.contacts.pickContact().then((contact)=>{
      alert("contacts:-->"+ JSON.stringify(contact));
      this.contact.displayName = contact.displayName; 
      this.contact.phoneNumbers = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value; 
      contact.birthday = contact.birthday; 
   });
}
```

Note : property name check and assign from response.

Comment: one more question with this i can get name but not displaying mobile number. alert("contacts:-->"+ JSON.stringify(contact.phoneNumbers)); this is working ,but <ion-input type="tel" [(ngModel)]="contact.mobile" name="mobile"></ion-input> out put"object object"

Comment: I think mobile number input not accepting value, try change input type or remove input type.

Comment: this.contacts.pickContact().then((selectedContact)=>{
      alert("contacts:-->"+ JSON.stringify(selectedContact.phoneNumbers));
      //this.contact.name = selectedContact.displayName;
      this.contact.mobile = selectedContact.phoneNumbers;
      //this.contact.bday = selectedContact.birthday;
    });    like this single field working but when i am tring to get more then one ..problem there

Comment: check my answer. you are not able to assign value properly.